# visual studio add on

Tags: visual-studio, add-on

I want to know if this is possible.  I have a small piece of software that I have written, that would work well if it can be incorporated into visual studio as an add-on.  Is it possible to create an add-on that when the user right clicks on a project, the drop down menu includes an option to select my add-in?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a graphic that illustrates more exactly what you want? Do you want it to work on solutions or individual files as well? Do you want it to only work in Solution Explorer?

Comment: Hi, Yes it would would on solutions, rather than individual files.  It would effectively call a resource from a shared network location and integrate my code into that solution.  It's a piece of software that creates a minidump file in the event of any unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165922.aspx is all about extending Solution Explorer.